# Zend MVC:: How can javascript file + javascript code inserted to partial for head or body area?

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-layout

How can  javascript file + javascript code inserted to partial for head or body area?

[Inside view simply call for insert to head to HeadScript and to body InlineScript - this not works inside partial(If I am wrong please write).
]

Thanks,

Yosef

Comment: The question is hard to understand. Can you try to clarify it?

Comment: Within his partial he wants to attach a script to the view it sounds like.

Comment: It looks like partials have their own scope, and dont "seem" to have access to the view. I may be wrong tho. From what it sounds like, instead of using a partial, you should be using a custom view helper.

Comment: Partials have the same scope as the calling view script, so the following works as expected (clean copy of ZF 1.11.5):

bin/zf.sh create project .

Comment: Ah okay, it looks like your right, its just a different scope, as you can pass variables through to the partial.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but have you tried using the following code inside your partial

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();

$view->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/somefile.js');
```

I know you were saying it doesn't work, but maybe its the method your getting your view instance?

In theory it should work.

Comment: not success to do it, var_dump(Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance())===null

Comment: Yeah , Are you using a layout? Im wondering if Zend_Layout will be null if not.

Comment: Also, Just out of curiosity, why do you need to attach the script within the partial, maybe theres another way to attack this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is far out of date, but maybe other like me having the same problem:

Make sure that you render your partial BEFORE you echo your headscript/links ;)
Took a while to figure out,.. but it does have some degree of logic in it :p

Answer (score 0):

try this work for me :D

```
<?php echo '<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile ($this->baseUrl(). "/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js" );?>';?>
```